# System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation property of Class.Property IEnumerable<AnotherClass>

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

This is new.  Its saying it can't work out the property. Which is odd because it's quite well defined.

> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to determine the relationship
> represented by navigation 'TcaOrganisation.TcaUnits' of type
> 'IEnumerable'. Either manually configure the relationship, or
> ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using
> 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

TcaOrganisation contains company definitions

TcaUnit contains vehicle definitions.  There is a required field that contains the id of an organisation

[image: Schema Diagram]

The relationship in question is

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TCA_Unit]  WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_TCA_Unit_TCA_Organisation] 
        FOREIGN KEY([OrgCode]) REFERENCES [dbo].[TCA_Organisation] ([OrgCode])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TCA_Unit] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_TCA_Unit_TCA_Organisation]
GO
```

Inside the `TcaUnit` c# class, the references are:

```
    [ForeignKey("OrgCode")]
    [Description("A link to the parent Organisation of this Unit")]
    public virtual TcaOrganisation TcaOrganisation { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ServiceProviderOrgCode")]
    [Description("A link to the Service Provider this Unit")]
    public virtual TcaOrganisation TcaServiceProvider { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ServerId")]
    [Description("A link to the parent Server of this Unit")]
    public virtual TcaCtrackServer TcaCtrackServer { get; set; }

    [Description("A Collection of Scheme Enrolments for this Unit")]
    public virtual IEnumerable<TcaSchemeEnrolment> TcaSchemeEnrolments { get; set; }
```

While in `TcaOrganisation` we can see the relationship that is causing the issue:

```
    [ForeignKey("ServerId")]
    [Description("A link to the Server holding the Ctrack Unit details")]
    [DisplayName("Ctrack Server")]
    public virtual TcaCtrackServer TcaCtrackServer { get; set; }

    [Description("A collection of Units attached to the Organisation")]
    public virtual IEnumerable<TcaUnit> TcaUnits { get; set; }

    [Description("A collection of App Enrolments for the Organisation")]
    public virtual IEnumerable<TcaAppEnrolment> TcaAppEnrolments { get; set; }

    [Description("A collection of Scheme Enrolments for the Organisation")]
    public virtual IEnumerable<TcaSchemeEnrolment> TcaSchemeEnrolments { get; set; }

    [Description("The Service Provider for the Organisation")]
    [ForeignKey("ServiceProviderOrgCode")]
    public virtual TcaOrganisation ServiceProvider { get; set; }
```

This error is occurring on the first call to the context. (Not using these two tables btw)  Why is my database schema suddenly invalid?  How do I fix it?

Comment: `TcaUnit` has two `TcaOrganisation` navigations, which one does the `TcaUnits` property relate to? You can add an `[InverseProperty("...")]` to distinguish between them. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=data-annotations%2Cdata-annotations-simple-key%2Csimple-key#manual-configuration

Comment: Post it as an answer and I'll accept @JeremyLakeman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every navigation property must relate to a single foreign key between tables. But not all foreign keys require a navigation property. See Microsoft's [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=data-annotations%2Cdata-annotations-simple-key%2Csimple-key#manual-configuration) for further examples.

Your `TcaUnit` class has two `TcaOrganisation` navigation properties. But `TcaOrganisation` has only one `TcaUnit` navigation.

EF Core can't determine which foreign key your `TcaOrganisation.TcaUnits` navigation relates to. You'll need to configure it explicitly, perhaps via an `[InverseProperty("...")]` attribute.

Comment: This also helped me find the issue on another class in the same namespace :D